# DJANGO + JWT TOKEN AUTHENTICATION

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

So I was trying to build a backend for my Android application. I was trying to apply a login procedure that works with JWT Token

This is what I have done :

1. I have made a custom User model.
2. Customize my superuser to take phone number and password, instead of username and password
3. I have successfully created superuser and store it in my database (using postgreSQL).
4. I have also customize my token claims and response as seen in my **serializers.py** of class LoginSerializer.

However, I encounter some problem after what I did :

1. Right now, after customizing my user model, I was not able to login to Django administration with my new custom made User model, even though I have succesfully created a superuser.
2. I still can't get the token even after I have made a customization for my token claims, with the success superuser account I just created.

Here are some of the error message :

[image]

[image]

Here are the some of the files attatched below :

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models   
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from phone_field import PhoneField

class RegisterUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, phone_number,password):

        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError('The phone number must be set')

        user = self.model(
            phone_number=phone_number,
            password = password,)

        user.save(using = self._db)
       
        return user
        
    def create_superuser(self,phone_number,password, **extra_fields):

        user = self.create_user(
            phone_number,
            password = password
        )

        user.is_admin =  True
        user.save(using= self._db)

        return user


class RegisterUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(name = 'first_name',max_length=255,default = '')
    last_name = models.CharField(name='last_name', max_length=255,default = '')
    email = models.EmailField(name='email', max_length = 255)
    phone_number = PhoneField(name='phone_number',unique=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(name ='birthday',null= True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=100,name = 'nickname')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default= False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = RegisterUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj = None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self,perm,obj = None):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,JsonResponse   
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from restaccount.models import RegisterUser
# Login
from restaccount.serializers import RegisterSerializers,LoginSerializer
# LoginSerializers
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView

from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

from rest_framework.permissions import (AllowAny,IsAuthenticated)
# from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView

class RegisterView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializers
    queryset = RegisterUser.objects.all()

class LoginView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework.serializers import (ModelSerializer,ValidationError)
from restaccount.models import RegisterUser
# Login

from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

from rest_framework import serializers

class RegisterSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RegisterUser
        fields =['id',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'password',
                'phone_number',
                'nickname',
                'birthday',
                ]

    def create(self,validated_data):
        first_name = validated_data['first_name']
        last_name = validated_data['last_name']
        email = validated_data['email']
        password = validated_data['password']
        phone_number = validated_data['phone_number']
        nickname = validated_data['nickname']
        birthday = validated_data['birthday']
        user_obj = RegisterUser(
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            email = email,
            password = password,
            phone_number = phone_number,
            nickname = nickname,
            birthday = birthday,
        )
        user_obj.save()
        return user_obj

    def update(self, instance,validated_data):
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name',instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.password = validated_data.get('password', instance.password)
        instance.phone_number = validated_data.get('phone_number', instance.phone_number)
        instance.nickname = validated_data.get('nickname', instance.nicknames)
        instance.birthday = validated_data.get('birthday',instance.birthday)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def validate(self,data):
        return data
    
    def validate_phone_number(self,value):
        phone_number = value
        user_qs = RegisterUser.objects.filter(phone_number = phone_number)
        if user_qs.exists():
            raise ValidationError("This phone number is registered")
        return value


class LoginSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls,user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        token['phone_number'] = user.phone_number
        token['password'] = user.password

        return token

    def validate(self,attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)

        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
        data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

        data['phone_number'] = self.user.phone_number

        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the password field in the model have to be hashed such that
user.set_password(password). This is also the same case, if you want to create a user from the API endpoint. You have to store the hashed password in your database.

However, I don't know why this is the behaviour.

Comment: Saving passwords as plain text is a serious security concern. In case your db gets compromised, the user accounts can be assumed to be safe as the hashed passwords are not reversible. Never save passwords as plain texts.